# How to edit nested JSON in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, data-class

I have a JSON model with nested fields which starts empty on which I need to, little by little, add/remove content.

Here is the JSON structure with its default values

```
{
  "id": "",
  "name": "",
  "age": 0,
  "address": {
    "streetName": "",
    "streetNumber": 0
  }
}
```

So far I tried both to have the JSON expressed as `String` and via Kotlin `data class` (using Moshi or Gson libraries), but neither of which allows me to easily change nested properties.

What I would like to have is a function that does the following

```
fun <T>addToJson(key: String, value: T) {
  // Finds the key in the JSON, if nested, maybe expressing the whole path to it (i.e. address.streetName)
  // Inserts the value in it
  // Bonus points if there was a way to 'determine' the type of the field so that I don't risk to set for the key `streetNumber` a value that is `String`
}
```

The ultimate goal would be to be able to call from anywhere in the app something like `addToJson("path.to.key", 25)` with the key either expressed as `String` or in any other easy way

Comment: Have you tried ObjectNode in Jackson library?

Answer (score 0):

this pseudo your asking as some problems.

1. what are you planning to do if the same nested key is used more then
   once?
2. T value has to be known JSON object type primitives arrays or JSON objects how you plan to enforce this in runtime?

here is an example on how to access each property inside your object

```
val jsonString = "{\n" +
        "  \"id\": \"\",\n" +
        "  \"name\": \"\",\n" +
        "  \"age\": 0,\n" +
        "  \"address\": {\n" +
        "    \"streetName\": \"\",\n" +
        "    \"streetNumber\": 0\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}"
val gson = Gson()
val jsonElement = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonElement::class.java).asJsonObject
jsonElement.addProperty("id",26)
jsonElement.addProperty("name","sof")
jsonElement.addProperty("age",33)
val nested = jsonElement.get("address").asJsonObject
nested.addProperty("streetName","blala")
nested.addProperty("streetNumber",12)

print(jsonElement)
```

Comment: So, for the same key being used multiple times I was hoping to be able to find a solution that could be used from everywhere in the app more or less like `addToJson(address.streetName, "blala")`

Answer (score 0):

Try ObjectNode in the Jackson (jackson-databind) library

You can build it from scratch

```
val factory = JsonNodeFactory(true)
val o = ObjectNode(factory)
o.set("id", IntNode(15))
o.set("name", TextNode("yourname"))
o.set("lastName", TextNode("lastname"))
val address = ObjectNode(factory)
o.set("address", address)
address.set("streetName", TextNode("Lenin"))
address.set("streetNumber", IntNode(5))
address.set("buildingNumber", IntNode(15))
println(o)
```

or load an existing json and modify it

```
val json = "{\n" +
        "  \"id\": \"\",\n" +
        "  \"name\": \"\",\n" +
        "  \"age\": 0,\n" +
        "  \"address\": {\n" +
        "    \"streetName\": \"\",\n" +
        "    \"streetNumber\": 0\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}"
val o : ObjectNode = (ObjectMapper()).readTree(json) as ObjectNode
o.set("id", IntNode(15))
o.set("name", TextNode("yourname"))
val address = o.get("address") as ObjectNode
address.set("streetName", TextNode("Lenin"))
address.set("streetNumber", IntNode(5))
address.set("buildingNumber", IntNode(15))
println(o)
```

I don't know of a library that supports multilevel paths in Json.
But it's rather easy to implement something like this:

```
fun setInJson(root: ObjectNode, objectMapper: ObjectMapper, path: String, value: JsonNode) {
    val splitPath = path.split(":")
    val lastName = splitPath.last()
    val notLastNames = splitPath.subList(0, splitPath.size - 1)
    var node = root
    notLastNames.forEach { nodeName ->
        node = (node.get(nodeName) as ObjectNode?) ?: {
            val newNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode()
            node.set(nodeName, newNode)
            newNode
        }()
    }
    node.set(lastName, value)
}
```

can be used as:

```
val json = "{\n" +
        "  \"id\": \"\",\n" +
        "  \"name\": \"\",\n" +
        "  \"age\": 0,\n" +
        "  \"address\": {\n" +
        "    \"streetName\": \"\",\n" +
        "    \"streetNumber\": 0\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}"

val om = ObjectMapper()
val o : ObjectNode = (ObjectMapper()).readTree(json) as ObjectNode
setInJson(o, om, "id", IntNode(15))
setInJson(o, om, "name", TextNode("yourname"))
setInJson(o, om, "address:streetName", TextNode("Lenin"))
setInJson(o, om, "address:streetNumber", IntNode(5))
println(o)
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know about the ObjectNode in the Jackson library. Though I'm not sure if it will reach the desired goal, which is from anywhere in the code to be able to do something like `addToJson(address.streetName, "Lenin")`

Comment: Now I get it, you want to use multilevel paths. I don't know of any library that supports this, but I wrote you a small hack for Jackson.

Comment: Ah that looks nice indeed :)
I guess it's impossible though to have a way to "validate" the `path` as if it was going down the fields of n instance of a class.
I'll try to see if I can do with this, thousands thanks

Comment: I don't see it's impossible to do validation. You can implement it with a map of path (String) to type (Class) and a type check - e.g. check that when setInJson is called 'address:streetNumber'  the value is an IntNode. Another (more canonical) way to do it would be a json schema (with a tool like this https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator), but it will not be optimal to use it after every modification, only after the whole json has been formed.